# Error: 'you must have a tty to run sudo' while using sshpass

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci, rhel

I have gitlab CI job which had a script execution like below:

```
  stage: permissions
  script: 
    sshpass -p "${PASSWORD}" ssh ${USER}@${HOST} sudo chown -cv user_a:user_a ${directory}/test.txt
```

The above gives me following error:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

If i add `-t` with `ssh` i get:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

If i add `-tt` with `ssh`, the job keeps waiting for me to enter the password.

My requirement is to execute a remote command using `ssh` and text password i.e. `sshpass`, is there a way i can achieve this without change any sudoers permissions over the server?

Answer (score 0):

Use somethinc like:

```
sshpass -p "${PASSWORD}" ssh ${USER}@${HOST} sh -c "echo ${PASSWORD} | sudo chown -cv user_a:user_a ${directory}/test.txt"
```

Example for write password from not tty to sudo:

```
echo ${PASSWORD} | sudo -S command
```

p.s. For configure servers use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), he handles such tasks very easily.